# A custom printf function using va_list returns weird output

Tags: c

I am testing a simple program using `va_list` on the STM32 Embedded system.

What I tried to use is a custom `printf` function which is the most famous example of variable arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

void myPrintf(char* fmt, ...)
{
    char buf[255] = {0,};
    va_list ap;

    strcpy(buf, "myPrintf() : ");
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsprintf(buf + strlen(buf), fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    puts(buf);
}

int main()
{
   int a = 10;
   myPrintf("Hello world %d\n", a);
   myPrintf("This is test %d\n", a);
   printf("Help me somebody %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

And the result is:

```
myPrintf() : Hello world 536872975

myPrintf() : This is test 536872975

Help me somebody 10
```

It should works, but as you can see, `myPrintf()` shows a weird result which is not expected and not understandable.  The original `printf()`, on the other hand, returns the correct result.

Since the optimization level is (-O3), I used 'volatile' in front of the variable declaration, but the results are the same... Therefore this is not because of the optimization level.

I was stuck so I tested the same code on PC, and it works perfectly fine...! but not on the STM32 environment.

[The code works on PC!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmQbj.png)

I don't think this is because of where it is executed but because of something else...

Could anybody help to solve this issue or provide some hints?

**Edited Dec.12.02:**

I added following code which parses format syntax manually between va_start() and va_end():

```
    while(*fmt)
    {
        p = *(fmt++);

        if(p == '%')
        {
            p = *(fmt++);
            
            switch(p)
            {
            case 'c':
                sprintf(displayBuf, "%c", va_arg(ap, char));
                break;

            case 'd':
                sprintf(displayBuf, "%d", va_arg(ap, int));
                break;

            case 'f':
                sprintf(displayBuf, "%f", va_arg(ap, float));
                break;

            case 'l':
                if(*(fmt++) == 'f')
                    sprintf(displayBuf, "%lf", va_arg(ap, double));
                break;

            case 's':
                sprintf(displayBuf, "%s", va_arg(ap, char*));
                break;

            case 'x':
                sprintf(displayBuf, "%x", va_arg(ap, int));
                break;


            default :
                sprintf(displayBuf, "%%");
                break;
            }
        }else
        {
            sprintf(displayBuf, "%c", p);
        }

        strcat(buf, displayBuf);
    }
```

As increasing the address of fmt, read formatting character "%" and if it exists, read the code such as 'd', 'f'. After that, convert the data manually using `va_arg()` and store to some buf using `sprintf()`.

and the results are correct.

It seems that when the custom printf function receives the string and argument as its params, it loses the data type of the argument somehow.

I still don't understand why I have to do this manually.
Moreover, This does not support full formatting syntax which is not implemented like `%.2f` or `%04x` ... :'(

Comment: It could be interesting to compare your implementation with the implementation provided by you c library on stm32.

Comment: Try changing your main to `int main(void)` and/or the first argument to `myPrintf` to a `const char*`. (These are the only warnings I can see on your code.)

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you for your comment! Actually, the code is simplied from the original source I use to figure out the issue, and `const char* fmt` is used in the original source code and shows the same results.

Comment: Are you sure this is _the exact_ same code you are running on stm32? How are you compiling for stm32, what compiler, compiler options do you use? What libraries do you use? What else can you share about your environment? How are you reading output from stm32? Are you running on simlator or on which stm32? Are you _sure_ you are running and compiling the correct file and executable?  Your code looks correct, and I can't reproduce with `arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nano.specs --specs=rdimon.specs` with `qemu-arm`.

Comment: I think your code is correct C. I guess you need to file a bug against the tools you're using. Of course, `printf("myPrintf() : "); vprintf(fmt, ap);` avoids the buffer.

Comment: @Mathieu Absolutely agreed. I will test the libraries which are used for the stm32 project on my PC.

Comment: @KamilCuk the code above is not the exact same code but it has been tested on stm32 and results were the same.  I am using STM32G474RET6, STM32CubeIDE 1.10.0 which is based on eclipse IDE with GNU tool for stm32 (10.3-2021.10). I read the output from stm32 via UART communication and not used simulator but actual stm32. Regarding compling process, I am quite sure it is correct since I got binary file and worked ok except the problem I mentioned above..

Comment: @PaulHankin You are right. I have been used this type of code for few years as my error logger, on PC. Hmm......

Comment: Is it worth trying to parse the formatting syntax manually such as '%d'?

Comment: @Ricky Tip: Do not use `vsprintf(buf + strlen(buf), fmt, ap);`,  Use `vsnprintf(buf + strlen(buf), sizeof buf - strlen(buf), fmt, ap);` to prevent buffer overflow.  Critical in error handling.

Comment: @Ricky BTW, `char buf[255] = "myPrintf() : ";` simpler than `char buf[255] = {0,};  strcpy(buf, "myPrintf() : ");` and better error check semantics.

Comment: `#define myPrintf(fmt, ...) do { printf("myPrintf() : " fmt, __VA_ARGS__); } while(0) ` is also a good trick

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thank you for the tip! It is much better to use vsnprintf instead of vsprintf although it does not solve the issue. 

Comment: What would be the output of `void myPrintf(char* fmt, ...) { va_list va; va_start(va, fmt); printf("%d\n", va_arg(va, int)); va_end(va); }`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I just tested your suggestion that manually fetching the argument from va_list and it shows the correct answer! :)) but what could this imply? I used `vsprintf()` which internally read/processes the formatting string such as `%d` or `%f`. I had never thought that I needed to do this myself, especially when I use vsprintf() or vsnprintf() function... Of course, it is needed when calculating function or something.

Comment: The value 536872975 (decimal) is 0x2000080F, does that ring a bell? This looks like an address to me.

Comment: @thebusybee you are right. It is the address that value is at. I think I have to pass this issue for now... because the code I added works fine now although it is not efficient at all. I will dig this out later and share if I get something. Thank you all!